# Repairing Lost Partitions In RAID Array

Tags: raid, data-recovery, esxi

I have a pair of SSDs in a RAID 1 array, managed by a Dell PERC H710 Mini. The disk backplane was replaced and the virtual disk disappeared, it has since reappeared but contains nothing (there was an ESXi instance here). What is the best approach to view/repair the disks? To my knowledge there is no physical damage to the disks nor have they been initialized since.

Comment: DMDE free demo version can be used to repair partition tables (MBR, GPT). As a data recovery person, I am compelled to warn you though to not do in-place repairs.

Comment: This looks promising, how do you mean 'in-place'? Do you mean I should repair with a different machine? Or as they are RAID 1 could I leave one and just work on the other? I'm aware of being careful not to write anything/make it worse unless I'm certain its the right thing to do.

Comment: What I mean is, if the concern is getting back the data, in place repair could solve the issue, it could also make it worse. For recovery of data it is not required the drives are repaired (in place), data can be extracted which is the safer option.